# esp32s: error: 'WDT_TIMEOUT' was not declared in this scope

Tags: esp32, c, watchdog

I am trying to initialize the watchdog timer.

I have installed

```
arduino-esp32-master.zip
```

I have

```
#include <esp_task_wdt.h>
```

set but it is not highlighted red indicating the IDE knows about it.

The error indicates that a major function is not present.

full error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Linux), TD: 1.53, Board: "ESP32 Dev Module, Disabled, Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS), 240MHz (WiFi/BT), QIO, 80MHz, 4MB (32Mb), 115200, None"

/home/brad/Documents/bradcode/Arduino/esp32s-infrared-ac-wifi-server-v4/esp32s-infrared-ac-wifi-server-v4.ino: In function 'void setup()':
esp32s-infrared-ac-wifi-server-v4:229:23: error: 'WDT_TIMEOUT' was not declared in this scope
     esp_task_wdt_init(WDT_TIMEOUT, true); //enable panic so ESP32 restarts
                       ^
Multiple libraries were found for "IRremote.h"
 Used: /home/brad/Documents/bradcode/Arduino/libraries/IRremote
 Not used: /home/brad/Documents/bradcode/Arduino/libraries/Arduino-IRremote-master
 Not used: /home/brad/Documents/bradcode/Arduino/libraries/IRremote-2.8.1
Multiple libraries were found for "WiFi.h"
 Used: /home/brad/.arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.4/libraries/WiFi
 Not used: /home/brad/Downloads/arduino-1.8.13/libraries/WiFi
 Not used: /home/brad/Documents/bradcode/Arduino/libraries/WiFiEspAT
exit status 1
'WDT_TIMEOUT' was not declared in this scope


This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

What library did I fail to install to get the watchdog timer initialized?

UPDATE:

My additional boards URLs

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/gh-pages/package_esp32_index.json,http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json
```

After following recommendations for poster, I got past that error and hit another one right away.

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Linux), TD: 1.53, Board: "ESP32 Dev Module, Disabled, Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS), 240MHz (WiFi/BT), QIO, 80MHz, 4MB (32Mb), 115200, None"

In file included from /home/brad/Documents/bradcode/Arduino/esp32s-infrared-ac-wifi-server-v4/esp32s-infrared-ac-wifi-server-v4.ino:24:0:
/home/brad/.arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.4/libraries/WebServer/src/WebServer.h: In member function 'virtual size_t WebServer::_currentClientWrite_P(const char*, size_t)':
/home/brad/.arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.4/libraries/WebServer/src/WebServer.h:144:83: error: 'class WiFiClient' has no member named 'write_P'
   virtual size_t _currentClientWrite_P(PGM_P b, size_t l) { return _currentClient.write_P( b, l ); }
                                                                                   ^
/home/brad/Documents/bradcode/Arduino/esp32s-infrared-ac-wifi-server-v4/esp32s-infrared-ac-wifi-server-v4.ino: In function 'void setup()':
esp32s-infrared-ac-wifi-server-v4:246:10: error: 'class WiFiClass' has no member named 'mode'
     WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
          ^
esp32s-infrared-ac-wifi-server-v4:246:15: error: 'WIFI_STA' was not declared in this scope
     WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
               ^
esp32s-infrared-ac-wifi-server-v4:251:73: error: no matching function for call to 'WiFiClass::config(IPAddress&, IPAddress&, IPAddress&, IPAddress&, IPAddress&)'
     if (!WiFi.config(local_IP, gateway, subnet, primaryDNS, secondaryDNS)) {
                                                                         ^
In file included from /home/brad/Documents/bradcode/Arduino/esp32s-infrared-ac-wifi-server-v4/esp32s-infrared-ac-wifi-server-v4.ino:22:0:
/home/brad/Documents/bradcode/Arduino/libraries/WiFiEspAT/src/WiFi.h:72:8: note: candidate: bool WiFiClass::config(IPAddress, IPAddress, IPAddress, IPAddress)
   bool config(IPAddress local_ip, IPAddress dns_server = INADDR_NONE, IPAddress gateway = INADDR_NONE, IPAddress subnet = INADDR_NONE);
        ^
/home/brad/Documents/bradcode/Arduino/libraries/WiFiEspAT/src/WiFi.h:72:8: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 5 provided
Multiple libraries were found for "IRremote.h"
 Used: /home/brad/Documents/bradcode/Arduino/libraries/IRremote
 Not used: /home/brad/Documents/bradcode/Arduino/libraries/IRremote-2.8.1
 Not used: /home/brad/Documents/bradcode/Arduino/libraries/Arduino-IRremote-master
exit status 1
'class WiFiClass' has no member named 'mode'


This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I have some library mixed up still

Comment: What do you mean you have "installed" arduino-esp32-master.zip? You don't install these things - you put the JSON URL in the preferences and install the board definitions using the boards manager.

Comment: @Majenko 
I updated the post with my URLs. I should have the correct ones already loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such macro in the ESP32 core. That parameter is just the number of seconds before a timeout occurs. Just pick a reasonable value. 5 seconds seems to be a commonly used (and appears to be used in the core) value.

Comment: setting the variable the line above caused the same error. So I deleted the variable all together and just plugged in the number 5. Now I am at a new error.  'class WiFiClass' has no member named 'mode'. I still have some library all messed up.

Comment: I have multiple wifi.h libraries as indicated in the errors posted. I just tried a different one and got past that other new error. Now I'm golden.